# Using Wordpress in CakePHP for views

Tags: wordpress, cakephp

I'm using the latest version of Wordpress for the public portion of my site and CakePHP for the actual web application. Since I want to keep the application consistent, I want to use Wordpress functions (for example get_header(), get_sidebar(), and get_footer()) to achieve this in my view files. Can I just use an require statement and call in the functions I need? Has anyone done this? Would there be any conflicts (e.g. functions with the same name) and is there a way to avoid it?

Additionally, I know CakePHP usually assumes path are relative to the app/ directory. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently tried something similar. You would be combining both codebases, and yes, there are name collisions. PHP5 namespaces would fix this, but [they are only planned for CakePHP 3.0.](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/development-roadmap)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about including certain parts of WordPress into a CakePHP app, it would probably get quite messy and WP might fail if its being loaded in a different path to what it expects. Unless someone else has done it before you might find yourself doing a lot of work and discovering that it can't be done at all.

There are some guides to installing them side-by-side, but nothing seems to cover grabbing posts, and parts of the template from WP in Cake.

Here are the some options I would think about:

1) Having WP located in /blog and simply make sure your WP theme matches your CakePHP layout visually.

2) Build a simple blogging platform into your Cake application.

3) Build the CakePHP part of your application as a WordPress plugin.